# Replace integer value excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm tyring to replace integer 7,6 in an excel by 8. However, following code is not really working as expected. It seems to subsitute strings. I have written a similar piece of code using the replace functionality but even that didn't produce the results I'm expecting. What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub MacroTest()
'
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Sheets("Naomi").Range("H1:H10000")

For Each cell In rng
    If cell > 0 Then
    cell = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "7,6", "8")
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Thanks for guiding me.

Answer (score 1):

I guess Taosique provided the best way to do it.
This answers why it returns `String` instead of `Number`.
You already figure it out that `Substitute` returns a string when you try it inside WS.
Try using `Val` Function then to convert the value to a `Number` as in below.

```
With Application.WorksheetFunction
    For Each cell in rng
        If cell > 0 Then
            cell = Val(.Substitute(cell, 7.6, 8))
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Or you can use `Evaluate` as well like this:

```
If cell > 0 Then
    cell = Evaluate("Value(Substitute(" & cell & ",7.6,8))")
End If
```

No need to enclose `7.6` with `""`.
`Substitute` accepts numbers as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
If cell.Value = 7.6 Then
    cell.Value = 8
End If
```